# Laravel 5.7 Multi Authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I created another authentication as Admin in Laravel 5.7 Additionally to its default authentication. They both function correctly but, the new authentication that I have created does no show error messages

[image]

For fault login attempts as default authentication does.

[image]

here the code I used for LoginController created for Admin model.

```
public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    //Validate the form data
    public function login(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',

        ]);

        //Attempt to lo the Admin in
       $credential = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,   
        ];
        //Attempt to log the Admin in
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credential, $request->member)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.home'));
        }
        //If unscuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
    }
```

Please tell me how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the code of these forms? Also, it's usually essential to share the code of what you need help with, instead of just the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to validate those data

// taken from the default auth controller

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
```

and in the blade file show the errors

such as

to diaplay all the errors

```
@if ($errors->any())
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif
```

and to display the specific errors

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
@if ($errors->has('firstname'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</div>
@endif
```

if you are not clear about that just watch the tutorial at

```
https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel
```

Comment: isn't following code correct?   ` //Validate the form data
    public function login(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',

        ]);

       $credential = [ 'email' => $request->email,  'password' => $request->password,   
        ];
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credential, $request->member)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.home'));
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
    }`